# Merge 'p' element content under the following 'p element' content

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

It is list content, right now bullet list and item content appearing separately in the output.
So I want to merge a `<p>`, Please look expected output and help me on that.
Thanks in advance

**Input xml:**

```
<kk>
    <group class="li">
        <line>
            <t style="li">•</t>
        </line>
    </group>
    <group class="p">
        <line>
            <t style="p">content here</t>
        </line>
        <line>
            <t style="p">content here1</t>
        </line>
        <line>
            <t style="p">content here2</t>
        </line>
    </group>    
</kk>
```

**Current Output:**

```
<kk>
    <group class="li">
        <line>
            <t style="li">• content here content here1 content here2</t>
        </line>
    </group>
</kk>
```

**Current XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="p">
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Expected output:**

```
<kk>
<p>• content here</p>
</kk>
```

Comment: It is not clear at all to me which rules you want to implement to merge elements. Perhaps look into for-each-group group-adjacent or group-starting-with examples or explain in more details in writing which elements are to be merged based on which criterias.

Comment: I want to merge 'group[@class ='li']/ki/p[@class = 'li'] content into  group[@class = 'p']/ki/p[@class = 'p']' content. Please look expected output

Comment: Feel free to explore e.g. `<xsl:for-each-group select="group" group-ending-with="group[@class = 'p' and ki/p[@class = 'p']]">` but that short snippet of input and expected output does not explain to me what kind of input you have, how many different group elements there can be and how you want to merge them,

Comment: @MartinHonnen: Thanks for your suggestion, I had explore with '<xsl:for-each-group select="group" group-ending-with="group[@class = 'p' and ki/p[@class = 'p']]">' but unable to get result, Thanks

Comment: Edit your question and show detailed, minimal but complete code samples of what you tried, how it failed.

Comment: OK thanks, I will try to edit but xml/xslt files has huge content and code

Comment: Hello, @KitaAnsari, do the answer from Martin Honnen works for you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70002848/14902377

If it's not, could you please add more complex input/ output part?

Comment: Hi @VasylKrupa: I have edited the input xml and expected output. Please look above and help me

Comment: @KitaAnsari, do you expect this output for corrected input:
<kk>
   <p>•content here</p>
   <p>•content here1</p>
   <p>•content here2</p>
</kk>

Comment: @VasylKrupa: No, My expectation output is <p>• content here content here1 content here2</p>

Comment: @KitaAnsari, I posted my XSLT code, please check if it works for you

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using for-each-group group-starting-with to merge any "group" of elements starting with that bullet:

```
  <xsl:template match="kk">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="group" group-starting-with="group[@class = 'li' and ki/p[@class = 'li'] = '•']">
        <p>
          <xsl:value-of select="current-group()//p"/>
        </p>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to place all nested p elements following code should help:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:strip-space elements="kk group line"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="kk">
    <xsl:copy>
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </p>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="group">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="line">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="t">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' ')"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My local output with provided Input xml:

```
<kk>
  <p>• content here content here1 content here2 </p>
</kk>
```